# How often are the low quality posts in the `/review` path re-evaluated?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, caching

After editing some questions and answers, I see immediately on the page that they have been edited.

However, it takes some time before these entries go off the page. How often is this page re-evaluated?

It would be handy to keep this in mind so that I can do some other useful things till it is re-evaluated...

Comment: The page shows a random selection of low quality posts. If you refresh the page you should end up with a new selection.

Comment: @jtbandes: The day/week tab doesn't contain enough posts for that to be a solution, for non-SO sites.

Comment: Ah, of course... on SO we have over 1000 posts in the week tab, so I don't think it would be much of an issue.

Comment: For sites where there aren't very many posts in the list, I can usually just remember which ones I've edited and not try to edit those again.

Comment: @CodyGray: Indeed, even better, the edited post shows a 100 quality score if done right. So this now serves as a "how often should I check the page for new entries?" purpose...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How often is this page re-evaluated?

```
int cacheDuration = 5 * 60;
if (tab == ReviewViewModel.Tab.LowQualityPosts)
{
    // this should run at most once an hour
    cacheDuration = 60 * 60;
}
```

I added a fairly hefty cache for the low quality tab, the reason is that it is very expensive to calculate due the need to crawl through each and every post in the set.